# Designing a small server on pi 4s cluster

Tags: server, cluster, raid

i am a full stack and mobile dev and i am slowly getting into infraestructure.

Since i am doing small apps for a maximum of 20 to 100 concurrent users, i want to make a small server and i thought of making a cluster of 4-6 pi 4 and use kubernates to manage the load. My only problem atm is having multiple AWS services which are getting a bit expensive since i am using tomó many services and instances. So making a small server in my home is becoming a better alternative, at léast for non productive or beta apps, i have direct fiber optic connection so i dont run into internet shortages.

My questions are:

1. Can PIs manage virtualization correctly, so i can have several instances of different nodejs servers? Like for example 4 clusters of 4 different projects?
2. About storage, i can use s3 services for allocating assets, but i would Need to run several dBs(mongo, mysql & posgresssql), PIs uses only flash drives which might be not the best usage. Is it possible to run some raid 4-5 under PIs?
3. Is this option viable, or buying some old used servers be a better option? So i can virtualize several VMs under one machine? Does PIs have any drawback i should account before buying all the hardware?
   At first i thought of making a Turing pi 1, but it doesnt offer any solution about storage, or they should be connected to usb? Or wait for turing pi 2 would be a better option?
   Thanks and sorry for my english, i know it is not the best.

Comment: theres a reason servers are not made of clusters of raspberry pi- it's inefficient once you reach a large enough number of concurrent users.

Comment: Thank @Abel, so making a small server would be a better and cost effective solution. I imagine it doesn't have much power, even if you cluster 4/6 pi 4s together it will still cost 300 bucks and performance still is not going to be the best.